# How get specific file storage service in flysystem component in symfony

Tags: php, symfony, dependency-injection, flysystem

I'm just wondering how to get specified filestorage instance in flysystem bundle.
For example if I have such configuration:

```
flysystem:
    storages:
        first.storage:
            adapter: 'local'
            options:
                directory: '%kernel.project_dir%/var/storage/storage/first'
        second.storage:
            adapter: 'local'
            options:
                directory: '%kernel.project_dir%/var/storage/default/second'
```

I want to grab it depending for example on some parameter in factory. Something like that:

```
$fileSystemStorage = (new FileSystemFactory()->getStorage('second');
```

and here is my factory:

```
class FileSystemFactory
{
    public function getStorage(string $storage): FilesystemOperator
    {
        switch ($storage) {
            case 'first':
                break;
            case 'second':
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

I just don't know how manually to define which options I want to grab from flysystem.yaml.

In documentation it says that I can inject it something like that (name camelcase from configuration):
https://github.com/thephpleague/flysystem-bundle

```
public function __construct(FilesystemOperator $firstStorage)
{
    $this->storage = $firstStorage;
}
```

But in my case I want manually define it depending on parameter.
Of course I can create two classes which have 2 different injections ($firstStorage and $secondStorage), and than return objects from those classes, but maybe there is some more simple way ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATED!!!**

I've got very similiar problem, and i solved it by using ContainerInterface and service alias (flysystem services aren't public):

```
// config/services.yaml
services:
// ...
    // we need this for every storage, 
    // flysystems services aren't public and we can solve this using aliases
    first.storage.alias:
        alias: 'first.storage'
        public: true
```

```php
<?php

use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerInterface;

class FileSystemFactory
{
    private $container;

    public function __construct(ContainerInterface $container)
    {
        $this->container = $container;
    }

    public function getStorage(string $storage)
    {
        $storageContainer = $this->container->get($storage); // ex. first.storage.alias

        switch ($storageContainer) {
            case 'first':
                break;
            case 'second':
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you read through the docs of the FlySystemBundle, you can see it supports lazy loading of storages on runtime:

[**Link to the docs**](https://github.com/thephpleague/flysystem-bundle/blob/master/docs/4-using-lazy-adapter-to-switch-at-runtime.md)

If setting this through ENV variable (or parameter) doesn't satisfy your needs, you can leverage the [LazyFactory](https://github.com/thephpleague/flysystem-bundle/blob/master/src/Lazy/LazyFactory.php) itself and use it directly via `Lazyfactory::createStorage` method.

If that doesn't suit your needs, you can copy the class and it's assigned [CompilerPass](https://github.com/thephpleague/flysystem-bundle/blob/master/src/DependencyInjection/Compiler/LazyFactoryPass.php) and configure it however you want.